# How do you define a multiline macro in C?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, directive

How do you define a multiline macro in C?

Comment: Use '\' at line endings.

Answer (score 28):

End every line of definition of macro with a `\`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX(a,b) {\
    printf("%d ", a); \
    printf("%d\n", b); \
}

int main()
{
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    MAX(4, 5);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `\` to escape line return:

```
#define MULTILINE_MACRO()\
    line1\
    line2
```

Answer (score 3):

Below are two C macros that are multiline

```
#define for_loop_begin(size)\
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) \
{ \
for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {


#define for_loop_end\
}\
}
```